# Why does using UITableViewCell from a unit test cause a Trace/BPT trap?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, ocunit

I have the following minimal test case in a minimal project created following
the GHUnit README:

```
#import <GHUnitIOS/GHUnitIOS.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTest : GHTestCase { }
@end

@implementation MyTest

- (BOOL)shouldRunOnMainThread {
  return YES;
}

- (void)testFoo {
  UITableViewCell *cell =
      [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain
                             reuseIdentifier:@"foo"];

  NSLog(@"cell: %@", cell);
  NSLog(@"cell.textLabel: %@", cell.textLabel);
}

@end
```

It runs fine when I use Build and Run in the simulator in Xcode. However, when I
run the following command in the terminal:

```
GHUNIT_CLI=1 xcodebuild -target Tests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator4.0 build
```

I get this output:

```
Running: /Users/<user>/Desktop/tmp/TestApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tests.app/Tests -RegisterForSystemEvents
Tests(39346) malloc: protecting edges
Tests(39346) malloc: recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder
Tests(39346) malloc: enabling scribbling to detect mods to free blocks
Tests(39346) malloc: process 39249 no longer exists, stack logs deleted from /tmp/stack-logs.39249.Tests.ac1JfL.index
Tests(39346) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.39346.Tests.t8LG4p.index
Test Suite 'Tests' started.
MyTest/testFoo 2010-09-06 23:24:25.006 Tests[39346:903] cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x5a6d190; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x5a6d390>>
RunTests.sh: line 28: 39346 Trace/BPT trap          $RUN_CMD
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 133
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 133
** BUILD FAILED **
```

This "Trace/BPT Trap" thing happens with OCUnit too, and I was hoping GHUnit
would solve it, but it doesn't on the command line. Anybody have any idea what
it's about? It seems to have to do with using UIKit from a context you're not
supposed to, but I don't understand what exactly the restriction is.

Comment: Ah, I added some more code and figured out that `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` is null when I run on the command-line; I assume it has to do with that. So is there an easy way to run unit tests that use UIKit classes without running the simulator?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of UIKit classes that simply don't work outside the context of a running UIApplication.  For instance, instantiating anything that attempts to use UIFont (UILabel, for instance) will explode messily (i.e. segmentation fault, or similar) outside a running UIApplication.  UIActivityIndicatorView will fail similarly.

There really is no way to consistently test code that depends upon UIKit outside of the simulator or device.  Fortunately, you can run code compiled for the simulator without actually running the simulator process.  I believe the GTM setup for iOS tests does this; I know that [Cedar](http://github.com/pivotal/Cedar) does this for iOS specs.  I'm not familiar enough with GHUnit to say whether it can do this.

If you want to run specs like this from the command line you need to set some environment variables appropriately.  You need to set DYLD_ROOT_PATH to the directory for the iOS SDK you're linking against, IPHONE_SIMULATOR_ROOT to the same SDK directory, and CFFIXED_USER_HOME to something non-empty (I use a random temp directory).  Once these are set you can execute the binary that you built against the simulator SDK by invoking it directly and adding -RegisterForSystemEvents on the command line.

For an example, you can check out the [Cedar Rakefile](https://github.com/pivotal/cedar/blob/master/Rakefile) (I'm most familiar with this because I wrote it; other equally valid examples may exist in GTM or GHUnit).  Look at the bottom of the file in the :uispecs task for the command line that it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar crashes when testing UIViews and UIViewControllers in GHUnit, when running from the command line because there is no interface for the views to be drawn to.

You should be able to test the logic in some of these classes as long as you don't call methods that cause them to draw themselves to the screen. You can init a view as long as it's not added to the main view hierarchy. Steering clear of drawRect in UIView and loadView in UIViewController was a help for me.

However, if you've got the kind of logic in your views that needs testing, maybe it would be easier to move the logic?